# Grabbing\spider protection

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, high-load, mod-evasive

There is a site\resource that offers some general statistic information as well as an interface to search facilities.  This search operations are costly, so I want to restrict frequent and continuous (i.e. automatic) search requests (from people, not from search engines).

I believe there are many existing techniques and frameworks that perform some intelligence grabbing protection, so I don't have to reinvent a wheel.  I'm using Python and Apache through mod_wsgi.

I am aware of mod_evasive (will try to use it), but I'm also interested in any other techniques.

Answer (score 1):

If someone's hunting exactly your website and data there 's really worthy - nothing will stop the smart enough attacker in this case.

Though there are some things worth trying:

- Keep counters of search usage from specific IPs and User-Agents. Block them when some minutely/hourly/daily thresholds are reached.
- Use blacklists of potentially harmful IPs or threat levels (for example you can use [Cloudflare API](http://www.cloudflare.com/docs/client-api.html#s3.6) for that)
- Cache the frequent search results to make them less costly
- It's probably a bit crazy, but you can render that statistics on images or via flash/java applets - it will make them much more challenging to grab
- A bit similar to previous one: use some tricky API to access search results, for example it can be ProtocolBuffers over WebSockets. So someone will probably need a full-blown browser to grab that or at least have to build some trickery around node.js. Downside - you'll lose legitimate clients using old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a [robots.txt file](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html). I believe you just put it at the root of your application, but that website should have more details. The `Disallow` syntax is what you're looking for.

Of course, not all robots respect it, but they all *should*. All the big companies (Google, Yahoo, etc.) will.

You may also be interested in [this question about disallowing dynamic URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495363/how-to-disallow-all-dynamic-urls-robots-txt).

Comment: Well, actually I am no suffering from Google of Yahoo, but from persons who won't respect robots.txt :)

Comment: Ah, well that changes things then :) Maybe add that to your question?