# Disallow pagination from being indexed

Tags: joomla, pagination, robots.txt

I have a joomla website with over 1000 pages that contain urls like this:

```
www.mysite.com/example.html?start=10  
www.mysite.com/example.html?start=20  
www.mysite.com/example.html?limitstart=0
```

All this URL are indexed by google, in google webmaster tool i have a huge list of duplicate meta description caused by theses paginations.

I know this is not difficult to block them using robots.txt thats why i need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a robot.txt and use the **Disallow** property.

For example, since you mentioned these 3 urls:

```
www.mysite.com/example.html?start=10  
www.mysite.com/example.html?start=20  
www.mysite.com/example.html?limitstart=0
```

you should use this:

```
Disallow: /?start=
Disallow: /?limitstart=
```

You have to use **Disallow:** followed by **/** and a pattern included in what you want to disallow. It can target specific files or folders.

You can also specify what bots you want to hide the files or folders to, by using the **User-agent** property:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /?start=
Disallow: /?limitstart=
```

the code above will work for any bot or crawling engine.

```
User-agent: googlebot
Disallow: /?start=
Disallow: /?limitstart=
```

this code will work only for Google for example.

For a reference you can read the material you find on [www.robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/) or also wikipedia has a page made good enough. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt

Another detailed reference can be found here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt

Comment: You are welcome. If you are satisfied with my answer you may upvote my answer and set my answer as "accepted answer". @NiceOne

Comment: Your robots.txt is wrong. The rule `Disallow: /start` *never* blocks a URL like `example.com/example.html?start=10`. It would only blocks URLs like `example.com/start` or `example.com/startfoobar` etc.

Comment: Ty for your advice unor, if it's wrong what should i put instead of Disallow: /start ?

Comment: I edited the answer. It should be okay now. Check the last link i added. I based the answer on that. @NiceOne

Comment: there is another question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495363/how-to-disallow-all-dynamic-urls-robots-txt?rq=1

Comment: Ty again Fabio i have rectified my robots.txt

Answer (score 0):

Correct Answer will be :

User-agent: *

Disallow: /*?start=

Disallow: /*?limitstart=