# Disallow search link on a website with robots txt

Tags: robots.txt

I want to disallow the search link on my site in the robots.txt.

After I click the search submit button, my URL will look like:

```
example.com/searching?k=something
```

How can I write this URL address into my robots.txt file?

My robots.txt file looks like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin_folder
Sitemap: https://www.domain-address.com/sitemap.xml
Host: www.domain-address.hu
```

```php
function search_k()
{
    if($.trim($('#country_id').val()) != "" )
    {
        //document.location = http_host+'/kereses.php?k='+$('#country_id').val();
        var KeyWord = encodeURIComponent($('#country_id').val()).replace(/%20/g, '+');
        document.location = http_host+'/searching?k='+KeyWord;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why don't just use asterisk? `Disallow /searchig/*`

Comment: You can also disable `query part`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495363/how-to-disallow-all-dynamic-urls-robots-txt?rq=1

Comment: What did you try? As you already have a robots.txt, you understand how it works, I assume? (Note that I removed the question asking whether you should disallow these URLs -- this would be a SEO question, which is off-topic here. It’s on-topic on [webmasters.se], but it’s likely already asked there).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disallow compliant robots from crawling all URLs on your site starting with `/searching`, then just add another exclusion to your `robots.txt` file after your other `Disallow` commands:

```
Disallow: /searching
```

For more details on the format, read more about [the de-facto standard that most crawlers adhere to](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html).